# Como contar o número de colunas em branco no MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, query, select

Eu tenho um banco de dados MYSQL de cadastro de clientes.

Eu preciso fazer uma consulta para saber a quantidade de colunas em branco que cada registro tem.

Por exemplo, no total tenho 15 colunas (nome, email, endereço, etc) e o "Fulano" só cadastrou o nome, então o retorno dessa consulta deveria ser 14, pois o total são 15 colunas e ele só preencheu 1.

O resultado pode vir direto da consulta MYSQL ou, se precisar, com a ajuda do PHP (usando foreach, for, ou qualquer outro tipo)

Obrigado!

edit*
Pro encquanto achei a seguinte solução temporaria

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE idcliente = 4;
```

e no PHP

```
$result = $db->query($sql);
$resultados= $result->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$count=0;
foreach($resultados[0] as $valor){
    if($valor!=''){
        $cont++;
    }
}
```

Aí uso o $count como a quantidade de campos preenchidos.

Comment: Já tentou alguma coisa? Qual foi o resultado obtido?

Comment: eu estava pesqueisand e não tinha achado nada, mas achei agora uma solução, não é a ideal ainda, mas deu para resolver, vou colocar na pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Ao verificar a [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) verá que `BOOL` ou `BOOLEAN` é apenas um sinônimo para o `TINYINT(1)`, que será representado pelos valores 0 e 1. Ou seja, ao somar os valores booleanos terá a quantidade de valores verdadeiros.

Com isso em mente e considerando que sua tabela possui as colunas id, A, B, C, ..., você poderá fazer:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    (A = '') + (B = '') + (C = '') + ... AS total
FROM <tabela>
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b8guJ64iUGuVgpesVM33e1/0)</sup>

Assim, as condições `A = ''` (e análogas) retornarão `true` quando a coluna estiver **vazia** (e não nula), somando assim a quantidade de colunas vazias.

Se considerarmos a tabela de exemplo:

```
| id  | a   | b   | c   |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | a   |     |     |
| 2   | a   | b   |     |
| 3   | a   | b   | c   |
| 4   |     | b   | c   |
| 5   |     | b   |     |
| 6   | a   |     | c   |
```

A saída da SQL seria:

```
| id  | total |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | 2     |
| 2   | 1     |
| 3   | 0     |
| 4   | 1     |
| 5   | 2     |
| 6   | 1     |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b8guJ64iUGuVgpesVM33e1/0)

Comment: Eu não havia entendido a pergunta. Estava escrevendo uma resposta nada haver quando apareceu sua resposta, obrigado.